# VB stream reader not reading properly

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to finish a school assignment and it's not exactly pulling out what I need from a string. Basically, I am making a receipt, I am creating one text file and saving the quantities of the order to it, and pulling `Cowboy.txt` to store the description and price of each item.

So on Line 16, I use a `StreamReader` to pull the contents of the `Cowboy.txt` file, and on line 17 I use `Split` to separate each line into an array.  So, `line(0)` should be `"Colt Peacemaker"` and `line(1)` should be `"12.20"`, since the code on line 17 is splitting the string at the comma. However, when I run the code, it puts just a `"C"` in `line(0)` and `"olton Peacemaker"` in `line(1)`. Since `line(1)` is being changed to a `Double` with the `price` variable, it is producing an error.

From my understanding, the code on line 17 is taking a whole line out of the `Cowboy.txt` file (`Colt Peacemaker, 12.20`) and splitting it into two pieces, splitting at the `,`. Why would it not be doing that?

```
Public Class cowboyReceipt
    Private Sub btnResults_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
btnResults.Click
        lstBoxReceipt.ClearSelected()
        Dim sw As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.CreateText("ItemQty.txt")
        sw.WriteLine("3")
        sw.WriteLine("2")
        sw.WriteLine("10")
        sw.WriteLine("1")
        sw.WriteLine("4")
        sw.Close()
        Dim total As Integer
        Dim srItemQty As IO.StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText("ItemQty.txt")
        Dim srItemDescription As IO.StreamReader = 
IO.File.OpenText("Cowboy.txt")
        Do Until srItemDescription.EndOfStream
            Dim qty As String = srItemQty.ReadLine
            Dim items As String = srItemDescription.ReadLine
            Dim line() As String = items.Split(items, ","c)
            Dim desc As String = line(0)
            Dim price As Double = line(1)
            lstBoxReceipt.Items.Add(qty & desc & (CInt(qty) * CInt(price)))
            total += CInt(qty) * CInt(price)
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here's the contents of `Cowboy.txt`:

```
Colt Peacemaker, 12.20
Holster, 2.00
Levi Strauss jean, 1.35
Saddle, 40.00
Stetson, 10.00
```

Comment: You are passing items as first parameter of Split. This is wrong because it is used as it was a list of character separators. it is just _items.Split(","c)_

Comment: Thanks Steve, not sure how I didn't notice that. SO I took that out and it is now saying line 19 is out of bounds, Dim price As Double = line(1). But if it splits at the comma, again there should be at least two elements in the array right?

Comment: In the future, when you run into problems like these, try to whittle it down do the simplest code that reproduces the problem.  For instance, you could have removed all the reading and writing with streams and simply set a string variable to a hard-coded value like `Dim x As String = "Colt Peacemaker, 12.20"`, and then split it, like `Dim fields() As String = x.Split(x, ',c')`, and then output the fields, and it would have had the same issue.  Once you narrow it down like that, it becomes easier to find your mistake.

Comment: Yes, it should if every line in your file has exactly a comma. Beware of empty lines at the end of the file. If you open your file with a text editor do you have an empty line at the end or a single line without the comma? In any case you should always check if you get the expected number of parts from your line splitting operation

Comment: Thanks you for the comments. I went back into the original txt file and there was a empty line at the end of the file, once I deleted it everything runs fine. Thanks!